# Particle JS is not working with SSR (Server Side Rendering) Angular and Scully

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, particles.js, scully, angular-scully

In my angular Application, I have added Scully for server side rendering. I have added particle JS to add animated particles as background of my component.

When I run scully `npx scully`, It creates static index of all routes but when come to particular route where I have used Particle JS, It took time and gives error -

Puppeteer error while rendering "/web/creativeHand" TimeoutError: Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded  we retried rendering this page 3 times.

I tried adding serverTimeout but still giving the same error. also adding `isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)`
but nothing is fixing it. I want a solution where It should not render the particle JS at server side and only render when It is loading on browser

Answer (score 0):

You can use the isScullyRunning method to check if you are in the Scully pre-rendering context

Template:

```
<div *ngIf="!isScullyContext">
   <!-- Particle JS Animation Code -->
</div>
```

Component:

```
import { isScullyRunning } from '@scullyio/ng-lib';
public isScullyContext = isScullyRunning()
```